# Finish() not working/App structure

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having an issue with finishing my MainActivity. I call `MainActivity.this.finish();` but all it does is remove the screen for a second and then it returns. I want the app to close completely when I choose the "Exit" option in my menu.

How my app works is like so:

- Listener (A library that listens for incoming calls and messages)
- Login Activity (This also has a listener implemented for registration and logging in)
- Main Activity (Once logged in - My app with a slide menu that holds fragments)

When going from the `Listener` to `LoginActivity` I do not finish `Listener` because I still need it running. Same goes with `LoginActivity` to `MainActivity`. I only call `finish()` when I go from `MainActivity` to `LoginActivity` using the exit menu item.

Using `adb shell dumpsys activity` I found my Task Records (shown below)

```
Running activities (most recent first):
TaskRecord{42fe4a38 #88 A com.example U 0}
  Run #3: ActivityRecord{42809ce0 u0 com.example/.activity.MainActivity}
  Run #2: ActivityRecord{425f8d80 u0 com.example/.activity.login.LoginActivity}
  Run #1: ActivityRecord{425ec3d8 u0 com.example/.activity.CallListener}
TaskRecord{429dc7f8 #2 A com.android.launcher U 0}
  Run #0: ActivityRecord{429da420 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}

mResumedActivity: ActivityRecord{42809ce0 u0 com.example/.activity.MainActivity}
mFocusedActivity: ActivityRecord{42809ce0 u0 com.example/.activity.MainActivity}
```

My question has 2 parts:

1. Why isn't my MainActivity finishing when I call `finish()`
2. Is this the proper structure to have? Should I have a MainActivity that holds everything or is this ok?

Any help on this will be great.

Thanks

Comment: Your LoginActivity is probably starting MainActivity again.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib ok i will look into that. Is this the proper way to structure your app though? Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @SherifelKhatib LoginActivity is not starting MainActivity again. The onCreate and onResume of LoginActivity don't even get triggered.

Comment: `onResume` is definitely triggered. Are you using eclipse? find the usages of MainActivity and tell us where are you using it.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib thats why I am asking this question. Its confusing. The first time I click it the MainActivity `onResume` method gets triggered. When I hit the exit menu item for the second time then the `onResume` method gets triggered in LoginActivity.

Comment: so you didnt answer my questions? Can you please include the usages of MainActivity. Most importantly where are you starting this activity.

Comment: LoginActivity did start MainActivity twice. I cleaned the project and it worked. All of them started twice. Shouldn't that show up when I ran the `adb shell dumpsys activity`? Also why would they run twice when I have one intent?

Answer (score 0):

to make sure all your Activities closed you can run next code to finish:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

About flags you can read in detail [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)